# Caption figure in Latex

Tags: captions

When I insert a figure in latex, i see under the caption the term "*figure*". The editor is **Gummi** on Ubuntu.

[image]

The code that I inserted this code:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Plot.jpg}
\caption{Input used to produce this paper.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, please show us the [code in reduced form to reproduce this output](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/)7.

Comment: I have upload it: http://textuploader.com/x4rr

Comment: Please follow the link, where it is explained how to *reduce* code to the minimum and add the reduced code to the question. The edit button is to the left of your name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing the code leads to the following [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/)

```
\documentclass{ieee}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{Input used to produce this paper.}
\label{fig-example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You get a warning, that package `caption` does not work with the class, commenting (prohibiting) the package loading solves the issue.

Disclaimer: The class is pretty old and IEEE has replacements.

Comment: Thanks, but if i want center the caption text of the figure, how can i do this ?

Comment: This is a class for submission to a journal. Ask the journal editors, they might point you to the new replacement classes. If you don't want to submit to IEEE, use class `article` to get your work done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a my guide to solve this problem on Ubuntu systems.

**1) Install the recommended  fonts**

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

**2) Install Gummi from Ubuntu Software Center**

**3) Install these packets for Latex**

```
sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-math-extra texlive-pstricks texlive-science latex-beamer
```

**4) Download the model IEEEtran from:** 
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/

**5) After you can open the model and use:**

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

In the figure, type **caption** in this mode:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Input used to produce this paper.}
\label{fig-example}
\end{figure}
```